# Prevent child state resets on props change

Tags: javascript, reactjs, use-effect, use-state

I am currently making a Graph component that fetches data from an API, parses the data to be used with a graph library, and then renders the graph. I have all of that working right now, but the issue I am having is with adding the ability to filter. The filtering I am currently doing is done by the parent of the Graph component, which will set the filters prop in the component which is then processed by a useEffect. But this seems causes some portions to re-render and I am trying to prevent. Below is what I have roughly speaking.

Rough example of Parent:

```
const Parent = (props) => {
    const [filters, setFilters] = useState({});
    //there are more state values than just this one also cause
    //the same problem when their setState is called.

    return (
        <Graph filters={filters} />
        <FilterComponent
            onChange={(value) => setFilters(value)}
        />
    )
}

export default Parent
```

Rough example of Child:

```
const Graph = (props) => {
    const [nodes, setNodes] = useState({});
    const [links, setLinks] = useState({});
    const [velocity, setVelocity] = useState(0.08);

    const createGraph = async () => {
        //fetches the data, processes it and then returns it.
        //not including this code as it isn't the problem
        return {
            nodes: nodes,
            links: links,
        };
    }
    
    //loads the graph data on mount
    useEffect(() => {
        const loadGraph = async () => {
            const data = await createGraph();
            setNodes(data.nodes);
            setLinks(data.links);
        };
        loadGraph();
    }, []);

    //filters the graph on props change
    useEffect(() => {
        //this function uses setNodes/setLinks to update the graph data
        filterGraph(props.filter);
    }, [props.filters]);

    return (
        <ForceGraph2D
            graphData={{
                nodes: nodes,
                links: links,
            }}
            d3VelocityDecay={velocity}
            cooldownTicks={300}
            onEngineStop={() => setVelocity(1)}
        />
    );
}

export default Graph
```

My main issue is that whenever the FilterComponent updates, while I want it to update the graph data, this seems to re-render the Graph component. This causes the graph to start moving. This graph library creates a graph which kinda explodes out and then settles. The graph has a cooldown of 300, and after which it isn't supposed to move, which is where onEngineStop's function is called. But changing the filter state in Parent causes the graph to regain it's starting velocity and explode out again. I want to be able to change the filter state, update the graph data, without re-rendering it. I've looked into useMemo, but don't know if that's what I should do.

I'm fairly new to React having just started two weeks ago, so any help is greatly appreciated! Also, this is my first post on stackOverflow, so I apologize if I didn't follow some community standards.

**Edit**

I was asked to include the filterGraph function. The function actually was designed to handle different attributes to filter by. Each node/link has attributes attached to them like "weight" or "size". The filterComponent would then pass the attr and the value range to filter by. If a component falls outside that range it becomes transparent.

```
const Graph = (props) => {
    ...
    //attr could be something like "weight"
    //val could be something like [5,10]
    const filterGraph = ({ attr, val }) => {
        for (const [id, node] of Object.entries(nodes)) {
            const value = nodes[id][attr];
            if (val.length == 2) {
                if (val[0] > value || val[1] < value) {
                    const color = nodes[id]["color"] || "#2d94adff";
                    nodes[id]["color"] = setOpacity(color, 0)
                    );
                } else {
                    const color = nodes[id]["color"] || "#2d94adff";
                    nodes[id]["color"] = setOpacity(color, 1)
                    );
                }
            }
        }
        setNodes(Object.values(this.nodes));
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: can you include the filterGraph function

Answer (score 0):

In your example you mention that filterGraph uses setNodes/setLinks. So everytime the filter changes (props.filters) you will do 2 setState and 2 rerenders will be triggered. It can be that React will batch them so it will only be 1 rerender.

Depending on what filterGraph does exactly you could consider let it return filteredNodes en filteredLinks without putting the filterGraph in a useEffect.

Then pass the filteredNodes en filteredLinks to the graphData like             graphData={{
nodes: filteredNodes,
links: filteredLinks,
}}

This way you won't trigger extra rerenders and the data will be filtered on every render. which is already triggered when the props.filters change. This is an interesting article about deriving state https://kentcdodds.com/blog/dont-sync-state-derive-it

Since you also mention that there are more state values in the parent you could make the component a pure component, which means it won't get rerendered when the parent renders but the props that are being passed don't change

https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactmemo

Also it's better to include createGraph in the useEffect it's being used or wrap it in a useCallback so it won't be recreated every render.

```
const Graph = React.memo((props) => {
    const [nodes, setNodes] = useState({});
    const [links, setLinks] = useState({});
    const [velocity, setVelocity] = useState(0.08);

    
    //loads the graph data on mount
    useEffect(() => {
    const createGraph = async () => {
        //fetches the data, processes it and then returns it.
        //not including this code as it isn't the problem
        return {
            nodes: nodes,
            links: links,
        };
    }
        const loadGraph = async () => {
            const data = await createGraph();
            setNodes(data.nodes);
            setLinks(data.links);
        };
        loadGraph();
    }, []);


const { filteredNodes, filteredLinks } = filterGraph(props.filter)


    return (
        <ForceGraph2D
            graphData={{
                nodes: filteredNodes,
                links: filteredLinks,
            }}
            d3VelocityDecay={velocity}
            cooldownTicks={300}
            onEngineStop={() => setVelocity(1)}
        />
    );
})

export default Graph
```

Comment: I appreciate your suggestions. I just applied memo to prevent other state changes in the parent from re-rendering the component. I still have the issue where the graph starts moving again on re-render. I think it could be fixed if cooldownTicks was 300 on first render and then set to 0 on all re-renders after. Do you have suggestion for this?

Comment: Well onEngineStop you will setState again for velocity so you will do a rerender since velocity will change to 1. If you don't want the cooldownTicks to apply again you could do cooldownTicks={ velocity === 1 ? 0 : 300 }